# What does "for i in generator():" do?

Tags: python, for-loop, generator

Can someone explain what each step in this does?

I have never seen "for i in X:" used where X is a generator, and I am failing to understand how the i interacts with the function if it's not being inserted between the ().

```
def fib():
    a, b = 0,1
    while True:
        yield b
        a,b = b, a + b
for i in fib():
    print(i)
```

Comment: This is platinum: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for loop` generates disposable variable if you use it like above. For example, a `list object` is used again and again in a loop but a disposable iterator is deleted automatically after use.

And `yield` is a term like `return` which is used in functions. It gives a result and use it again in loop.
Your codes give you the number known as fibonacci.

```
def fib():
    a, b = 0,1 #initially a=0 and b=1
    while True: #infinite loop term.
        yield b #generate b and use it again.
        a,b = b, a + b #a and b are now own their new values.

for i in fib(): #generate i using fib() function. i equals to b also thanks to yield term.
    print(i) #i think you known this
    if i>100:
        break #we have to stop loop because of yield.
```

Answer (score 2):

Any function that contains a [`yield`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement) will return a [generator](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html#generators).  The for-loop runs that generator to return values one at a time.

When you run:

```
for i in fib():
    print(i)
```

The actual mechanics of running the generator are:

```
_iterator = iter(fib())
while True:
    try:
        i = next(_iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    print(i)
```

As you can see, the *i* variable is assigned the result of calling *next()* on the generator to get the next value.

Hope that makes it clear where the *i* comes from :-)

Answer (score 1):

`for` just ranges over the vaue of the expression. If the expression calls a function, then its value is whatever is returned from the function, so the for ranges over the result of that function.

Note that here though `fib` is not a function, it is a generator. It successively yields the value of each step.

Comment: I did not know that a function was not a generator. Is there a link you can point me to that explains the difference between them?

Comment: Quick Googling reveals [this](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/) and [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). That was more a subsidiary point though: the code would work just as well if `fib` was a normal function that returns `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, the for would still iterate through it.

Comment: `fib` is still a function. `type(fib) = <type 'function'>`.

Answer (score 0):

To understand this you will have to understand what `yield` keyword does. Please take a look at this: [What yield does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python)

Now you get an idea that `fib()` is not a function it is a generator.
So in code:

```
def fib():
    a, b = 0,1
    while True:
        yield b    #from here value of b gets returned to the for statement
        a,b = b, a + b
for i in fib():
    print(i)
```

Since `While` never gets a false value. It keeps running.